# Reordering DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E
1  a   a   a   a   a
2  b   b   b   b   b
3  c   c   c   c   c
4  d   d   d   d   d
5  e   e   e   e   e
6  f   f   f   f   f
```

Anyone knows how to reorder it using Pandas to make it look like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1  a   a   a   a   a   b   b   b   b   b
3  c   c   c   c   c   d   d   d   d   d
5  e   e   e   e   e   f   f   f   f   f
```

I tried reading the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html. Its difficult to understand as a beginner, appreciate any help.

Comment: Which operation were you trying to do, and what specific part didn't you understand?

Comment: Perhaps `df.to_numpy().reshape(n, m)` will get you a step closer to your goal. Also, if you wish to solicit help, [post your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the logic for the reshape? How would if generalize to a (n, m) shape?

Comment: @mozway The login is - every second row to go back of the row above it.

Comment: Then you can reshape the underlying numpy array (see below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to group every two rows in a single row, use the underlying numpy array and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

out = (pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(len(df)//2, -1),
                    index=df.index[::2])
         .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase)))
       )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  a  a  a  a  a  b  b  b  b  b
3  c  c  c  c  c  d  d  d  d  d
5  e  e  e  e  e  f  f  f  f  f
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for. Is there a way to give the same output using Pandas library?

Comment: This is using pandas. Pandas is built on top of numpy.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have the index same as previous index. 1, 3, 5....

Comment: Use `index=df.index[::2]` as parameter in `pd.DataFrame(...)`